# Succes method of $.Ajax does not work in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I read almost all post about the topic. But Unfortunately I can't handle my problem. The problem is really awkward at least for me:
I have a simple C# code to retrieve tracking status of submitted factor in ShoppingController class as follow:

```
  public string StatusOfFactor( string guid )
    {
        // note that guid was being trimmed in javascript

        Factor factor = (from Factor fact in db.Factors
                         where fact.TrackingCode.ToString() == guid
                         select fact).First();
        return factor.StatusOfFactor;
```

and I have a javascript function which call this method as follow:

```
function TrackPurchase() {
    var txtTrackingPurchase = $("#inputpeygiry");
    var guid = $.trim(txtTrackingPurchase.val());
    var urlMain = 'ShoppingController/StatusOfFactor';
    alert(urlMain);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urlMain,
        cache: false,
        data:  guid,
        success: function (returnVal) { 
            alert("I am sucess function");
            $("#StatusOfFactor").html(returnVal);

        },
        error: function (e) {
            $("#StatusOfFactor").text("nothing is really exist");
        }
    });    
}
```

note that I have a textbox with `id="inputpeygiry"` which receive tracking code of user. above javascript function is call by clicking bellow button:

```
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" id="btnpeygiry" value="Track Purchase" onclick="TrackPurchase()"/>
```

so the problem is that the success function never call!!!
Would you all please help me to solve it?

Comment: have you got the right url? see if 'Shopping/StatusOfFactor' works

Comment: the path is as follow:     public class ShoppingController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        #region Status of Factor for Tracking a purchase

        public string StatusOfFactor( string guid )
        {
            // note that guid was being trimmed in javascript

            Factor factor = (from Factor fact in db.Factors
                             where fact.TrackingCode.ToString() == guid
                             select fact).First();
            return factor.StatusOfFactor;

        }
}

Comment: do 'shopping/StatusOfFactor' in your ajax request. I think that will work (I think mvc drops the 'controller' part as default behaviour)

Comment: I checked it. but still doesnot work. I also clear my history all the time. but nothing happend. I really need help

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? Callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

See documentation of [jQuery Get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlMain,
    cache: false,
    data:  guid,
})
.done(function (returnVal) { 
    alert("I am sucess function");
    $("#StatusOfFactor").html(returnVal);

}).
fail(function (e) {
    $("#StatusOfFactor").text("nothing is really exist");
});
```

Comment: <script src="~/Js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Then why aren't u using `done` and `fail`? It's available since version 1.5.

Comment: I make the code as follow:    function TrackPurchase() {
    var txtTrackingPurchase = $("#inputpeygiry");
    var myGuid = $.trim(txtTrackingPurchase.val());
    $.get("ShoppingController/StatusOfFactor", { guid: myGuid })
    .done(function (returnVal) {
      alert("I am sucess function");
      $("#StatusOfFactor").html(returnVal);})
        .fail(function () {
      $("#StatusOfFactor").text("هیچ فاکتوری با این کد رهگیری یافت نشد");
  })    but still the done function never call

Comment: Can you debug the Controller action? The parameters are filled correctly, the action returns the right value?

Comment: Yes I Checked it. I make it as partialView and it obtained value from the db.

Comment: is it necessary to put my input type button in form tag?

Comment: No not anymore in HTML5

Comment: Use visual studio debugger and browser debugger for debug from a to z.

Comment: when I use this Ajax.ActionLink with manual guid, I get the result:    @Ajax.ActionLink("پیگیری خرید ", "StatusOfFactor", "Shopping", new { guid = "29ea78df-61ed-48dc-85f9-457b3630c3e6" } , ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "StatusOfFactor", HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btnpeyment btn btn-xs bg-color-btn" })

Comment: but how should I call javascript function in Ajax.ActionLink(,,new {guid = a javascript function to retrieve textbox value,,})

Comment: I want to know how to call javascript code IN Ajax.AcionLink to obtain textbox value?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GET` to `POST` and it should work fine for you.

**Controller code becomes :**

```
[HttpPost]
public string StatusOfFactor( string guid )
{
    // note that guid was being trimmed in javascript
    Factor factor = (from Factor fact in db.Factors
                     where fact.TrackingCode.ToString() == guid
                     select fact).First();
    return factor.StatusOfFactor;
}
```

**Javascript code becomes :**

```
function TrackPurchase() {
var txtTrackingPurchase = $("#inputpeygiry");
var guid = $.trim(txtTrackingPurchase.val());
var urlMain = 'ShoppingController/StatusOfFactor';
alert(urlMain);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlMain,
        cache: false,
        data:  guid,
        success: function (returnVal) { 
            alert("I am sucess function");
            $("#StatusOfFactor").html(returnVal);

        },
        error: function (e) {
            $("#StatusOfFactor").text("nothing is really exist");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why use `Post` when he wan't to get a value?

Comment: I also change my browser, but it couldn't help me.

Comment: is it because of the order of my scripts? my scripts order is as follow:        <script src="~/Js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Js/SearchJquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>